# How can using Jena read file from HDFS and convert it to Rdf?

Tags: hadoop, rdf, jena

I'm using Apache Jena to convert a .csv file to .rdf. I use `model.read(pathFile)`, but it only reads file from the local filesystem. I want to read from hdfs, such as `model.read(hdfs://....)`, but it gives an error.

[image: My code]

And the error is:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.riot.RiotNotFoundException: Not found: hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser/demo/departments/part-00000.csv

How can I do it?

Comment: can you show us   your code and what error you are getting?

Comment: @vefthym I add my code on below

Comment: Please, edit your question with those details. Do not add answers that are not answers. For now, I did that for you. Follow this practice in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add a `Locator` to the `StreamManager` to handle "hdfs://".

Jena does not ship with code for reading HDFS URLs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have a question, Can you use Spark to run the method ConverDept() to speed up the execution?